# Android Application crashes on some devices on notification receives

Tags: android, android-intent, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I am using the following code for creating a notification in Android. But its working fine in some devices. But when I checked in Samsung Grand, it crashes while receiving the notification. Android version 4.1.2 ( both devices )

```
private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {

    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, message, when);
    String title = "From Application";
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("message", message);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent intent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notification.defaults|= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
    notification.defaults|= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
}
```

Any idea ? I am new to Android..

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to post the crash log.

Comment: Thanks for your reply... I found in logcat that I didn't enabled the VIBRATE option in Manifest file. Problem solved when I added that